# The jlabel can't be positioned as I want

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, bounds

```
private JLabel basicRule;

public TutorialFrame() {
    setTitle("Tutorial");
    setSize(800, 800);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    
    JLabel basicRule = new JLabel("OneCard Basic Rule");
    basicRule.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 50);
    add(basicRule);
}
```

I clearly set the position of `JLabel` called `basicRule` to (0,0) through `basicRule.setBounds (0,0,800,50);`. But when it's implemented, it's in the center like a picture. Why isn't the location set?

So, what other methods should we use to set the location as we want?
I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you know, how.

[Left aligned label in center of height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy8h0.png)

Comment: Your tutorial is misteaching if it's teaching you absolute positioning.  Oracle has a better tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  skip the Netbeans section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check how to use a `Layout Manager` : [Oracle guide for layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)